# It it possible to catch and handle website unload event - asp.net web pages razor 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

Is it possible to detect when a Razor 2 Web Pages application (asp.net) is being unloaded - for example, as a result of IIS/WebMatrix being stopped?

There is _AppStart.csthml to handle the application start.

Is there something similar for "application stop"?

EDIT:

Low reputation, cannot vote up/answer myself yet.

I have added Global.asax and indeed there is Application_End event for handling app shutdown.

Can I use that instead, or your method is preferred?

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using the "DomainUnload" event handler on the domain the aspx.net application is running in.

eg;

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_DomainUnload;
}

void CurrentDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cleanup code here
}
```

Hope this helps,